# WEBI find duplicate rows (with exception of certain columns) and highlight

Tags: business-objects, webi

consider the following table:

```
+------+------+----------+----------------+
| Col1 | Col2 |   Col3   | Numeric Column |
+------+------+----------+----------------+
| ValA | ABC  | Value 3  |            101 |
| ValF | DEF  | Value 10 |            101 |
| ValC | DEF  | Value 10 |            101 |
| ValB | GHI  | Value 12 |            103 |
+------+------+----------+----------------+
```

I would like to find duplicate rows by comparing values across multiple columns, and highlight the values in the [Col1] column when duplicate rows are found (OR highlight the whole row, whatever is easier). So in the above table I would like to compare values of the [Col2], [Col3] and [Numeric Column] columns.

And in this example, ValF and ValC in [Col1] would be highlighted. I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, see steps below.

1. Create a dimension variable and concatenate all the columns you like to compare into a variable.

- Variable name: Concat_col
- ​Variable formula: =[Col2]+[Col3]+[Numeric Column]

2. Create a measure variable and refer to the first variable.

- ​Variable name: Count_col
- ​​Variable formula: =RunningCount(NoFilter([Concat_col]);([Concat_col]))

3. Create a measure variable and refer to the first and second variable.

- Variable name: Max_col
- Variable formula: =Max(NoFilter([Count_col])) In ([Concat_col])

4. Now create a Formatting rule:

[image]

5. And populate as follow:

[image]

To apply to a whole row, select the columns one by one and click Formatting Rules > 'Conditional Format' (this is the name of the formatting rule we just created earlier).